# Is it possible to use Pydantic instead of dataclasses in Structured Configs in hydra-core python package?

Tags: fb-hydra, hydra-core

Recently I have started to use [hydra](https://hydra.cc/docs/intro/) to manage the configs in my application. I use [Structured Configs](https://hydra.cc/docs/tutorials/structured_config/intro/) to create schema for .yaml config files. Structured Configs in Hyda uses [dataclasses](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html) for type checking. However, I also want to use some kind of validators for some of the parameter I specify in my Structured Configs (something like [this](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/validators/)).

Do you know if it is somehow possible to use Pydantic for this purpose? When I try to use Pydantic, OmegaConf complains about it:

```sh
omegaconf.errors.ValidationError: Input class 'SomeClass' is not a structured config. did you forget to decorate it as a dataclass?
```

Comment: In addition to the answers below, it might be possible to use [`hydra_zen.hydrated_dataclass`](https://mit-ll-responsible-ai.github.io/hydra-zen/generated/hydra_zen.hydrated_dataclass.html) in combination with [`hydra_zen.validates_with_pydantic`](https://mit-ll-responsible-ai.github.io/hydra-zen/generated/hydra_zen.third_party.pydantic.validates_with_pydantic.html), though I haven't tried it myself.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For those of you wondering how this works exactly, here is an example of it:

```py
import hydra
from hydra.core.config_store import ConfigStore
from omegaconf import OmegaConf
from pydantic.dataclasses import dataclass
from pydantic import validator


@dataclass
class MyConfigSchema:
    some_var: float

    @validator("some_var")
    def validate_some_var(cls, some_var: float) -> float:
        if some_var < 0:
            raise ValueError(f"'some_var' can't be less than 0, got: {some_var}")
        return some_var


cs = ConfigStore.instance()
cs.store(name="config_schema", node=MyConfigSchema)


@hydra.main(config_path="/path/to/configs", config_name="config")
def my_app(config: MyConfigSchema) -> None:
    # The 'validator' methods will be called when you run the line below
    OmegaConf.to_object(config)


if __name__ == "__main__":    
    my_app()
```

And `config.yaml` :

```yaml
defaults:
  - config_schema

some_var: -1  # this will raise a ValueError
```

Comment: Nice, looks good!

Comment: Kıvanç, have you been able to get this to work with [custom](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/types/#pydantic-types)- or [constrained](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/types/#constrained-types) types? I get ValidationErrors. I would prefer to use such types instead of @validators.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me. When you call `OmegaConf.to_object()`, it converts the object to a `dict` instead of a `MyConfigSchema`. Because of this, `MyConfigSchema` is never constructed and the validator never runs.

Comment: @Emre I don't think it is possible to use types other than what python [dataclasses](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html) support.

Comment: @Antyos are you sure you are using the Structred Config you register in your `.yaml` file (in `defaults` key)?

Comment: @KıvançYüksel That's what I was missing! I was always curious what the purpose of the `name` parameter in `cs.store()` did. Thank you! It might be helpful for other people to include a sample YAML file in the response and include the import of `omegaconf` so it works as is.

Comment: @Antyos Glad it's working now! :) I have already edited my answer based on your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

See [pydantic.dataclasses.dataclass](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/dataclasses/), which are a drop-in replacement for the standard-library dataclasses with some extra type-checking.

Comment: This doesn't work directly, but using it together with `OmegaConf.to_object(config)` it works. Thanks!

Comment: Hey @KıvançYüksel can you give an example of how u used this?

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to provide an update as Pydantic and Hydra have changed since this question was first posed.

Here is how to do this in 2024 using an updated (but similar) `config.yaml` file as above:

```yaml
defaults:
  - config_schema
  - _self_

some_var: -1  # this will raise a ValueError
```

and a similar schema:

```py
import hydra
from hydra.core.config_store import ConfigStore
from omegaconf import DictConfig, OmegaConf
from pydantic import field_validator
from pydantic.dataclasses import dataclass


@dataclass
class MyConfigSchema:
    some_var: float

    @field_validator("some_var")
    @classmethod
    def validate_data_dir(cls, v: float) -> float:
        if v < 0:
            raise ValueError(f"'some_var' can't be less than 0, got: {v}")
        return v


cs = ConfigStore.instance()
cs.store(name="config_schema", node=MyConfigSchema)


@hydra.main(
    version_base="1.3",
    config_path="conf/",
    config_name="config",
)
def main(cfg: DictConfig) -> None:
    """
    Main function for running experiments.

    :param cfg: Configuration object.
    :type cfg: DictConfig
    :return: None
    """
    validated_config = MyConfigSchema(**OmegaConf.to_container(cfg, resolve=True))
    print(validated_config)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```